# SocialEngine photo issues

Tags: socialengine

I noticed that when a member profile photo is being changed a feed is automatically published which is perfect, this feed contains a thumbnail of the updated member photo which when clicked (I'm thinking is meant to open something like the smoothbox or some lightbox for preview) opens on a new browser window and load the image direct url into the browser window.

Could this be a bug or just my installation working against me :). Is there anything i can do to fix this pls.
Thanks.[image: Screenshot of the image feed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Patched it..

application/modules/activity/views/scripts/_activityText.tpl

line 126

```
$attribs = Array();
```

should be changed to

```
$attribs = Array('class' => 'smoothbox');
```

and you'll have it displayed in smoothbox.

Answer (score 1):

It's not bug dear, it's default functionality of a socialengine. If you click on enlarge image it will take you to the original image.

Comment: ow!... but is there a possibility of integrating a lightbox or smoothbox thing to open the image.. Cheers